I'm stub a DAO's method which is wrapped by Mybatis PageHelper Plugin,however it dosen't work
I'm testing some old code,which used Mybatis PageHelper Plugin, with Mockito.
The class to be tested:
import com.github.pagehelper.ISelect;
import com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper;
import com.github.pagehelper.PageInfo;
class AService{
private SomeDao aDao;
   public void aMethod(){
            ...
            ISelect iSelect = () -> aDao.queryById(queryStatement);
            PageInfo<Stuff> pageInfo = PageHelper.startPage(pageNum, pageSize).doSelectPageInfo(iSelect);
            List<Stuff> stuffs = pageInfo.getList();
   }
}

Test class :
import ...
class serviceTest{
   @Mock
   public SomeDao aDao;
   @InjectMocks 
   public AService service;
   .....
   @Test
   public void testMethod(){
     List<Stuff> list = Collections.singletonList(new Stuff());
     Mockito.when(aDao.queryById(any(QueryStatement.class))).thenAnswer((inv)->{
            System.out.println("stub of aDao.queryById is called");
            return list;
        });
    ....
   }
}

then I got an empty list when pageInfo.getList() returned,why ?
I used 'System.out.println("stub of aDao.queryById is called")' to verify the mock of the dao object method is actully called ,when excute the 'doSelectPageInfo()' method.I expected the pageInfo.List to be the stufflist I provided,however it's empty.

You should be stubbing aMethod and not queryById. When you mock the dao, you create a stub of the methods and not the body.
